# EC2 Caching Code and Server Error 500

Tags: amazon-ec2

I started to mess around with the EC2 “Micro Instance” for a new site i’m working on.  I put on an ubuntu lamp server and loaded up our favorite php framework and started along the coding path.

One frustrating thing i’m finding is whenever I make a mistake coding (which is rare!   j/k), it gives my a “Server Error 500”  and won’t display the php error line number or the helpful references to where the mistake might have happened.

Also when ever an error does appear and I try to fix the mistake it will remain the same for a couple of minutes.  Its like its caching on my system or something.  If I do something like this :

echo "test" //leaving off the semicolon 
refresh the browser it comes up with the error.  Then when I fix it:

echo "foo"; //corrected 
I still get the Server Error 500.  Not sure if anyone else has run in to these issues.  Maybe its a php.ini configuration, .htaccess configuration (i’m using Paul Irish’s HTML5Boilerplate .htaccess code), or a LAMP configuration issue.  Any pointers to where the problem might lie would be a huge help.

Thanks!  Steve

Comment: Joomla often serves an unhelpful 500 error if it generates certain types of errors, depending on configuration.  This is more likely a result of your PHP configuration... http://www.troubleshootingwiki.org/Error_Handling_-_Joomla_1.5_Development_Cookbook

Comment: In my research on trying to find a solution I have seen that other PHP frameworks have the same problem.  I'm using CodeIgniter for my App.  I had the idea that many since i'm using a micro instance and the data storage relies on EBS, that when the error occurs, and I upload the fix, there is latency for the servers to populate the fix?

Answer (score 1):

this has nothing to do with ec2.
see php error directives in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini